# How to create html template and how to send them through email without attachment

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

currently am working in asp.net c#..one of my client wants to send html template through email donot as attachment ..so i created attachment like this

please refer the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<head>
    <title>saloc</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
<table style='width:90%; border:3px solid #C0C0C0;'>
        <tbody align:'center';>
            <tr>
            <td align:'center'> 
                <table style='width:100%;padding:0;'>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <td align:'left'>
                        <table style='width:100%;padding:0;'>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                            <td align:'left'> 
                                <table style='width: 100%;border:0;padding:0';>
                                <tbody>
                                    <td align:'left' valign='top' style= 'width:15%';><img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAN0AAAA7CAIAAABwuxjSAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAAOwgAADsIBFShKgAAAQ0tJREFUeF7tfQd8XNWV/oSEYgwuktVG02c0M+puAkwLEMgSkkDYsCEJKWQ3WTb03gKBhBCKqTYGTHHvHTfce5flIsmS1Xub3tt7M+f/nftGsrMLu3aWZP/5/Xx9NPPmlXvPPfc77d73nlV0rpwrZ1ZSgySfRn+jcg6X58r/cUmlUklRKEGJJAWJwudwea78n5chXLrJ30eOMEVkip3D5bny/2M5h8tz5a8sp/yvR7jeKMWJ/BR1UrSbfAEpkgpGcU767LMs53B5rvyV5RQu+2qDH7+7ZlRm/deGbVFpB371VOyTxRSIUgKnnMPlufJVlC/HkYRj0SiF4skYUSAYTkaS8VlTajKGp1Sq2AXntapUTd9QVY0e5f36hSGVqkp1fv2Nd5A/6icK9jTDnoIUHJ8JWM/h8lz5i/JlkEnKiVSSogmKyUBocsDZTw0nqi84ny5RDZxn2jfpm8GqDUlPPXVXHb37tsYJxdHzR9MFWs/rr7uTMgUDcPGgc7g8V/7K8qWQSciSTAlgiwDMoH/7hkaVqu1ruXS8PpHyxSgWw6WAnofiyVScItR9ZNPVpUHVhb3//phPjmEv6Bwuz5W/snwpZADKFCwlzohLjvYtKlXXRSMoknJsWtG4dWPv1s2e9evcaz7rXDcj3t5EsYQ/EEpRbHuxPq66mLYcjiTioHO4PFf+yvLl9jImS1EKpFJSwHXTN5OqMT31tRF3wDmuwDNKFVepoioVXaQKq5iOX3g+0nMKSORqP6hS9V84UokvAetILPrlbZwqaVymYJ5BuADfYn1JCQiwISrBXoS9qBaUxMmnk7JXIS7K1hm0fXpBPfyFD6GUStPpPXwk/SWKsj3080sKGPhPlL4O3ZTQiMzM8+70ehqiJ3QQnzhJOXD2RVyk1JDkhritwdpOJ3EOupwW7+Ceof3pnSn+wDkQiJCGcoJy5BRx4S8cQqckiUnUgB1K35Tr0qeeuvALKT2I/7VEcUgiOUHejhaVqrroKh6oRKT3Mp2kUgWeeCWGn5GB4NyP6NIL6MILO//4Dk5wU9D/1jOS6gJadoAJ9YO7MyiMS4Et5FgJDh/wLT58RC6igWg0IMWkFLAeoSQojJwMJ8cJsI/FkhHwGqAkci4QNvhib4rXks6o9XQBA9FUFEJhBmTUQ15CSELRUBLNYqccY2WTYjySUjKWYpciQp3Bosg0XZQfIMAPzOJc/hRgRyCUSKAjMoUQEoFHbyzqTXKCyRJPhEmOUhInEDdyqsYzKjg9KscSqEGOE3hNIKiKUDxKCeCEmY2idZkigWA0EoCPQ5fRbhB5hIz2wEssLgdBYZwYjyFei4PAcoLcMlufSNgnNIpFq1iNtPZiFytATEr6guQNUjBIcW4S5/Fl4hOnQgZRiidSCtCxA62DlHr8MUJugg2c+8UlhprigUAvHd2KXMe/ehOGBLV3Xa2Ofk3lfvAPMtiISyFK1I5Upb6m6njsOQpLHsAk0Ri48BvdN3wfhN6CW6Fj/0P5S1wKZiU5hR8DSYCd2xJWJERhFwU8FAlSDB13UsxLFJIkf4KiLgr2JL2gEPorJRihfRHGwRkXwYC4AAyICnzCliiSjXY7xLClDY+IrhWRfjEuk7Aa+IGDEfQoSTFE3MKnAAwQfU83JYMy+fvD3TCZqFfxL4xXwEiOoL/ACWP2LItoUwx6KkERCAOiBLKiSBIYN7ATMqQIoQIzQG2QEhhEmfsBPnF+zE1J9NuHpAEKyNXhYJzCMjmgRtyAJIcC2D8ELHxyqIaegmMetFCUgi7yBlgnkhROkkesN3MTgnABBgiqAq1X2AOhjYQAMcQmAdRf0vMUxjsUjHvbl8wKwGX3A8nYl+i+0uxTqbrvfSJK7niwKzrjwy6Vyvk1lWvROmYMME84q89TNV00EiR1OIApcP4/liE/Lv6YbwqFIS2xB6J0e8jrpZCHwl5ye6nLQah6wEs+/OyhOPrtjZJfHHPHGU4hcjhpwAWzJio+s4LG2PFx69BpdJjVChLs7eHWYVbkZDQaj8WlSCQiR0PCpCXSLnKogvSmwCWgFY3L/jAqTEFfIAkQLgoJSxb3BKT+OHrldjIAMNIYfFeQhzWFw+wrQF8yPv9tgRmMRCWJ3SjS0nAUWECvoHLAFQDiBze8COzupxDUO0SBCLmD1NRF/Q4KOSjBFJL7wFss6OPreFzT7MdhSdmyDvYWhG0QRgsEFUvFPQmfj8IQkDMSCIdh+8FTLBzs49YlSHKAzUhvC7l7qbmBenqZHC6CtmBAcSkahXJGYW0iEvgBwwk/xWGVGK3+iA/j07psvuvC86jNiT0YpK4rrHSxyndR9snsHGemyX2egYYPa1Cpkv1u5p+VxVH9NVV0eA4o0dx7drhM95DHVgw2tiNxCoSoD0Dsdc5duO2Rpz654XvTJ94wf9J31n33JzWP/d47az7VHKXQADkbSYYeCLF6Ou8fX0aNDWx+zrygRZwOEjxA+DxL5nfvnjJ57iP3QiVS4IR5w1EWGSsMB1FfjEveSqaAS8WwdJ9oDHc7gs3d1D5A7X3U1Ul9LdR6hNpqqbOPmnpSte3U2k+tA9TUGu5s9QVdHjZcZ41LNDtkyRTzhEGBHgT9PRTrp1gvuVvI00U7NnfMnL36oac/uP2up8dOeOe662de9a35N31n7+OPOZfNB1FdFfl6KOQXRhRBTNIbhKlX4J1ghYfFhWVT4lelSaa0KwmkEoi3lNBBhvUMtAE8FGghb3Nq95qql54++Oh9C2++cXrFhJnXXM10/TdX/OiO2pdfDK9YRFX7qR8icrO2xF3Uf5Jqj95fVk7+ANpB6x6EbZ98Sl9X+WQPj1Ei4LjaElSp2vMy6r4+rBaWEqa0pioaBNhT/bgEIAo76rF/VDYo2NAJvuCVWF7/bRG4VCQqc6/gYLj//ijBzHT2tj71uzdH589Xj5uXX/GB+bJ3rBPfNY2fpi75eFTBR8P1s7XFW2+5nZYupo6TTHWVtHz+n806amtl9Jx5gQwV4cpwrcJIhGRqqHnn+vFPFamp4QhQzmCD94GZxMAoJECsFHwrhJJAnAbfhKMI5hye919547Ff//bnFde8Pv5a9GXmiMxV2dlzLr3wk4suWpNvnzHG8scMw6uWsX82Fj5tsbz1sx9Wb1jKRoVBhSrOokB6HiI3x9nEYbiIEPwyLKWXvK104oD/icfmjsr9TF08fXTBn/PL/2Sv+PRb35p22fg3dPp3cnSz82yzx1hAS03jd3z7dtc7U9msAscc18TCfh9zhAAESJUQbAwiHwKBFxZazZ5A8O0JBWScg5gEHfE304HPjj/yqzfVmTNy85bk619TnT9Lb35br/to0gTQlKvGP2fXPpE76oXsjAVjx1b/5F9p6Xbq8FJzDTmb3U8+/a6lCKYSgwM1CMQ8tHE5XajqOngo5QFyQ47xuUjD3Y8+wRwsmE7nXbB82BhauJE9RDyAOI+o/9j5qkZDMUh2cxzCE/T/UxnEpbBVkCM0lGBp/CE6eHT2ldcuq7h8SfH4mepy72OTaXslHTxOh6rp8An6aHHDHb/5ZIxpZo55sbnowyw1aNcN3/ogP+/1rBHUchI5i6j/zAoYYFCCDTYPzIcnSkvnTjONWnJNYfVLj1MslEqlwm4HSUgLhZEADSFxcPPUDmUL8QiCOh/HvaxmW3e3/PjntUWl7SZTf4HZXVh6IstyzHblzutvpdlLqLOb+rupu4ECHSR7U1EAjMfizAvORp9bfSHgBfgIwZGjL8gEepuP/empZy5SbSsp3Wqw7S6/hqYtpI2HqbWPelqoq446Gqn6OL0/49D1t4NWZhet15Uu0tsWTrqCdq6nCHyfFyFpvB8mCkoLAKIdKC4+AVBYEhFAJ+CEJcCHBQNDC+cbdNPhXcce+/Vk9cWrKkrnW/Rz1Br5md/TyrV09Bh1tpGji8ndQe42ajoqz/lo6x0/mKI1v5lhWzrxnxLvve185sFN+YaPR+bSyVZ0EEqQCkdooMXxDdXJ234ZD0aR1PRfb0ypVJ3/8QQGrVfuqRxbTJdmHlENA6cS+frBzuaF0W9cRK/MZWJsn5G2n7KXCLOg6AiZydVHtdXPZ2YtGT9h1dVXL/rutwm5QjhIEXgWP4WR/bhhiMjXS4f3Njz0yMJhuW32q0HNxvFVJeOn2tTUVsVyOcuShCcCz8hUAklq6mz46Q83GjO3Fqmnl+moq4k9OFAL4ukqnCecuEKD3wrJMLrKloJgnA5CsBVy06Fd8wz5R6zmzkJbbZb6iKZoW+nVHN4hivV7yNFBkQERCMYSccj57OwltwVIutmQo/FkOMBp4qbN86+6ZqbesPHyireMalo6mzzd5BugEII2mMBuirdRvJs8LRRzkJ8pOXfu5xXX7M4vOm4q/9xkjb3xGjnbKdjLWot8BhKQkJVFwpweCZM5iEu0G0VqBcsaDZLP4Zo+9cNi67rysp2TJr1fYDzx3OPUdAyoohicex/F/MwGCHlCxElRBwcbgVaqr1p5+y9n2a5YZC/YUVrQUzZ+7kWjyIHMIeFFDyHJVOQIHLcqAzkQRSK1Nxpl1fnNv3ucfSw46K6JXywmMl+b5Y94KeCu1ptCqvNTzhQIV5/d/CUqxDVirkeivubpl5dtvrJidVnJsm9fz6OV8CP1RtAgBQYo7qMUTkQ+7qJ4P3U206vTNl6QD6rLLj5oKnqvSEPthznZPOMCPqNJyQ9dBBLCEvwQ7T2wYPTwExb1UX3GYmOWZ+0ilmMc+aMUiSK15gCTmVbwN1jJ0C+eJFN+oELAJYTMSeKEN9y7/rvX7yo0H87L6i4t36svdj/yHLkR7COlYM+IkxDao14pjsvOsuAKX4qjJw+SxQFkxm3vvTXLXrSldMK28oqlY8dDKyjULQXbIekU8okUYriuZLwdCXc45XRBmDwCfgo6qLnp+LU3VuYXVGrMi3Ny9973b4wnQvIhOpKE18D1iXDaIwjFE3F5KoFTIjD89c8+MdOiXW0vWGEtmq4z08oV5Onne9Ao6JW8uJBrkaMgEYvGUgkvUtg4hjXaT86g4+U3P9Bl7Su31KrzP8/V0q79LFRczLlXzHloY4dK5fr2P3t94Vk3j98xbETNP/84OOX9ELPUWzm+okY1bM4FGphM1+Q/xlRfa7nr52AddNbrPTgRKhfgdDrZ9/bvFhXm7io2fQSPfHCL0C2RasSRJoY5vuFZCHgQmFc361lfb+q1t0GfWUo2lY9/IXMYHd8Lz6vUfCYFgkUfgErmF9ho62z91389ZDM1GfK6DJojxZY1d95Crk4KBCF74AYmguPg/4JL1AMa3CG2FFzyXikOQxjrb3jmgc8t2lqbscZsXpVnoI/nwBUggEdAiiECQQ7pq05VdEYFV8DGBtFxqJCnO/T2y+9nDq+cMHazzTZdY6Ct2ynghQtGyq5MyEWg5MIXA1v4jVEXH9C4IIX64d8/u+HyLRbjHqttuc26455fwazGOHzlKUyYLkA4xCDl5Ad7oFUcm8N3e13tzz49JzfrcKltnSn/dYuJdu0mj1tMa0Kx4U3IFUKsxkwo7SoSAhs8W4fAwOsmj6P+jw98ah5RX1a4YFQG7TsoIodkOIlsB1ck9vziNhqZ03LtT2FE5B5v5K333RpLApx75VA4HoI1jwb7Zs+ULhy2Z5imu7sxFZBBZ4dLnMUqg1Y5dKaPSjJ3FGVUl+j2X19BvSd5foEnvWBReYafuxKOsxtJwWmEpNgABfrJ1QvafdfPFo+b8IHRSCdqYOGVBs6kQChoHU0zMN1+qj+5xmLYmDuqo6zQaTA3GI3Ly82sIWFEipIr4oZygP4bXA7uE1sAGSglSbBPkf6WJx/YbMk/YdNVF+iXa7XJmTMJgRLHrQAlV4oa+Hz09FQtZ1QgmK6ED7kWHA7NnLY8b2TvVRN2aXMWqbNpxgyeSYPKicgiAi2AqeNQBy2lmeTpKtG6cAU4uYO2Llms11SaCqqspQuNhq3P/pYSvfCnobgMBQCBW2VAhJFISMiRgw7nO5OnX3xJW0VFlT53kXqUZ+FsEYCFeLoNgxhiDmLAp7h8iFCJIjoOk/g2Cxe5j26++6atVv3sUZm0ax8aSaZgmbgtTiodrc0ZF/lUI7rvfzDe0SaJ1ZCAi6d9PSkpEvfQ2oWHR18cPe9iac4iNlHATPgs18fFtDZUFsQzl++OVh2zX9pkyw7d+3Pyd8AE4JA/KXmlOEYuPdJCiEGC9ffxN0ecbqqsfEtfMF9bSJX17DrPuKBKeD/0mYvbI73w/Ba9eqV+TGWZrUNnacvXb8nP7Hj0HrY3STigRCgVBonBFBeLgm9lXBVK71ZO4GMSRf3k7nU+/B97DNlN1qwaa/YyfZY0+0P4dwYTj9QgDS0enl2BWiHkc9K+bSv0OSd02U36zP22vP23foscvSwQiA/VgzlOn2OpeIRbwE/sF4cUiIi7vwEcFzk7/L+9b1+W/oTaXKUzL9Ln+D58CwiDv0aogesgACAFhtPFrbpI7qX1i6dnja412uqy1I3l9pbf3MmmF4aV5/CjjMsoiMWN3im9hdgVUHJhHRaTUMi0Ek3UuGW2NneNvTy0cDnzzAsWfGI4HgsCC30duws0A6qve1WqymGjfVP+7Ph8Hi3+tDIvr131jYRqWKPqQtqwszcUdblga2Ogs8Ul+GNoKot7m8dlnTBe0Gwc0fb968jbLSc8EBIgD+LwJ85xBrgLJhHIxhCPhoFLuCSQ173mzp9NyzDRkdazxWUwHmdmYZidfSvtlm0WdfdDv1hSYmi2lXXkmur12pVWHbWfpCjiWkATKBtMbvgyLvgGV0N06oiyhcGEwXC7nA/ft9uQ02DPPVaYs9CYFZ8zXaxdIZkQcMGn4hfTF59N4RAjSM6ubf90/T6zrlmb2T3WODP3G7R1KeeISHTibGoGUSDxgiozNojLwflz4NLPAAnSQCcdOrxRY643FQ6Mm1BVaPjEnEtNDUBlxCtW1KBPIQqkEBqHE6keirZ8UKw7UlLUZypu0xasys+ivRspNBBFLIq4C7FPHDGYiJ+xIfo6hEvuLv54aNH9pCwHUqlOVNj91ONTsnWeuUu4g6cVRTzxaMzv9vgf+mXtsEtCfN/GeSnVJQ2qkQfVtu6pH8E/nAkEv7CkcakMJMsmmVhflNlkHt6lH7169DBqPMHJXTQA7VJW7fyS7JPZj3BkhJ9yhK1szAuCv+iav+AVcynVt/Pa2hkXNA1x8UK230krFyzUZC3MH0H1O1f/5DuVtrGdmuLWfP3avDG+GVOQLyd8GLjByxQa/KUgcogGj6RPg8ApFG958pnPreajxcYDJYbZFl143lyeecEh6BH6A3xglMSQn3b9mRVkyn53dMZHs9U5uwzaujLzjnLN/FvKKcTrDv5EWE6xIeYUS8x7wIKlmWYrdWoDkgAX7piP5CC5+3f+yw8PX3HZNm3mieuKPjYPr/r9MzyL5w4wn8olKEnEjh0H//AfKwty6wx6R0HZ3mxt1c9/wrl22J8MIy6HIid4UgXhEq9YcnqnhOkg+ENhPQenL/DJqTOi5HY6Xv1uaUXPnMWimVNFFnOQSJ0SETEjCDD3ODlQCXtT8bCcRNbNVux/hUsUvhwNgWM5skQ7vKcor1+ftStrZP1DD1NXFycxOBRHaMFBL4YPuIRY4LcSPOMtJaI+EAL2RM2Re/Vmamrn4P7MC6pAvbwY2Lv21hvm5I1su/cnFKpzr/p43ui8HktF/Rh1pdW0/FsTyNeRHHCw4AZHUcGcqCO9+3RKS0VEHWAbOUbjU88Cl9VFxqpiwzyzLjp3NnDJ3Ud/MF74TA+McuXZFERtba3rrr1uR0Hh0QJ7pd28zK45+c7TlOiQyeuUAywR1AzHJKcQ9/gGF+GVBpVDTBwNsNXkQDPkj86etdCg3WPN3z82c/815o+LLHToKM8RpVhgfCHsn89B7VVTCzOPlhpO5ud1FpSszDOl1n7GNiXBs+EMPPYDkpwMx1IB1IsUYZAYo9wauixEGgkzp6kI7FGQunq2/u6FNS+8xIyeViSYVF4EEYtMwb4ohRBL+KQgXI9TSrhiEdh0iPt/h0tcqwiFF1T8K025nXZNnyart7R4DpzIy5Opr5NkqHeEnVGKk5NQLM5f0A/oIRQGqE3FZLjymP/RKy6nrl42HmdeFIkEkrR940fqS+cW5NDxLRQ4Rv76z4rGNZkm1uVbqotsn2qG0bYVfE8KuFXoi3CpDK6yPXiQtxmXsVDnk4/tMaq7CnKaC7I+042huR8iSMa4KZcIcCIBQv4nbhw5qxKO0Np1szNyW0qvbDSU1VnHzc1R08EdFO1NpjxBCsd4qUYYYwmhJYYQdg9Bn7h3AwJkywWEcLoNC+SEyYxGuLO1jTNHjO67csJx47CTZTnLM0d7XnwJeEXoheQcDCP5pPZOeu/1jUXqOktum0XfMLZidtFY6urGQV4PiqHttN4hcg3wwrw/PS3PhN2D02rKSiZiCGyDT4xvJFy9fs2iya+IHp4qfDyRSN8iA8OIy3A+dw2QgN1Nr8Z9RbjkOdvQdEPufrO6FWpnNB2wj51VWLrrqUepoRpOCmrP6EyhZdGeRIEeD18LXWSCDCL7P51BMGlJTqGUglN5xhyugc/hH0pr6WPYg9/okjfR/x+/XWPI3XvX96nnGLJbind7nnx6b7a5xVp8sti2s9R44O5/IR/PsQ5eL64V3Cj7RKOoEahiEk2nj/J8btTf8+RDB4y5PZasDnPmOm0GzXmfoN5sNpD2AZEJjFyI7+KDHxD1KiTK0K/BHSjKOaL7wWDnI4/tMduP5hgb8m2H1dZ5eQbq6yZPL8aec1icyVFPgl0qO5QwGkJzPOeZQvwX4fBaYrkBMrCXwAsNeKjXtbls4nGTvs2e3WweXWvQb738CnJ1AWwAEIsB2O3rP3DtVfvVmfX6zCa7cZPOuOPOX8APwK0heAAx2uQU7EeYZx4A1KgwygohjBmEkfjtEIuoApfYD5yFm48e5FUAsJfkeTRmDKfihL9ZSftxLpAHkrW41DPljYV208mikvq8/CPq/PrxY3cUFS4qttHC2eTu5rw74ZdlDgihDEjLOEVjJAghhcX8aZhveAwDFjxmLBR+MiQpbv3yYVRY7iAJOMZV6B7EADresOKSnI3Z+bFlM8nXxIF/2E0H9n6Wld1sMZ3Ua/cZLO9k5VBvN8/SBd2waqiZaw8x70powTNnIpaC3MGDQOcgZNFWKND9+KO7jZpWq6bBpl1pyKW5nyDvYYsl+iACCp6awIUseuwTXQDhQ1SFgVIQz+fzLALqRVYMefR0T9eoDxfo6y36Rpv5uMV66OZbyOsC4HAti0uRM2+i4+g2h0BoTsR2SsWMb7Si4IXPhy/yuNwPPbozP7+xzNRWqOkwGpbnZFPtPsgnAbTjUnjbvbtWZGR1Ggx1pjGHreo1sNPTZiAXQi4peE8zL+g05odIOUMURVz4TB9MnyCSdDFNoVTFZfCSv0VR8h4eD26YcQm71Tfzuqu3FxbXGgs6i+zHcsacNOkPW4zz1Vm7f3QbHd5HARfFQ0GPM57g8DguiztYIUjwC2kDeUmIFXm6wCVv4wicLxLSWMrDhiMocMnPJ+EStIjfbm/3e1O3GAvXmAqovxFM8EoGFNvR1fbvP4f9brCajhQUrS4qO/LMoxR2gCQZQZa4nG9n4zq4piB+AJdshBA5oRJF0CDWn0Cw+/HHdpiAG8MJu3GZUZOaOwOxB09ECEwwUwwUIXNlYBT6YlyiISCDnS9nuMePz9Xk1hQA8fkNhZpKs+HEXT+GrFLs7ZgBfApiRHI10B/OHrgqrm1wmJWTsYv3SEHUEHnhD5vUmupiU3ORrsugWafOim5axG48GmXti/p9SxdAn3v0hlpL1oFizYrcPJq7jEIJruQfszAuIeV0RsZ30UL/XNRUPV1n2F9cXmW2dIwbV2c3VmqzTxQU1JSWL9XoGh98kPo7eFmPQxu2SUpdqCAVT8LYK+OHT5assJdcOYxlIiFHMSC8h50AGzYxnR2RaaD7jWvHTSvU9rz2HAKyFJtEmW+Iirvja+dPz790f7F+V4Fuz7iij/U51N3MFPLF0TgqAgCFweWa+bYGNJ7GJVpVAMGM4OurwyUbe/wCLhVjmUiENmxYatA2Fuha7Frgcrch3/H4wxRyJsWsMCfjoto0LqHRYkZGtPgFuIQt5eAMjjfoomnvw2kctusai7RtZvUWk/rk1JcQfrBjRTjg9tb87tkdBlOrWVdtyz5Upp+nzqEtO2FPFc7/EUsalyLwFyPKNqePl2i3b5tvK1pttG7X6+tspmazDoneiXzNCXvRBovpTV3OCQDI00qRfkCHkgEmEZOhAoiVxTE4nAKXGB20wKAEgFhWGAvskZNSRNxSuXrJi5pLXxyvIXc9SY5Aws2BP3MYo/6WxddM2FakQwZdVajdosukj6cx+b2caoggG3UCmqJa9Af6ASjAyfG6hmhd7EfbZ4VL/CnjKggfDK9BXMZ5aQybiBLFanMi0TJz1lqTqc1s7CjUN9h127RZqTdfprATx1g3lHr4A1ISuGS3qLT4F7jEyeA5xrfyoUGkPk5asmRZRsYBa35dkabZot5h125+6Jd8ky94gB72uDd89/b9hXZ0qtqec2ic8UPNGKqt44dGUBda+AcsaT8uVnqEc0FPMMSBfr4/tKFp3c3fX2mxNdsLW5AGlVobyixVtvwTE+xrsy/dVGRaMs5OG5ZRsIuCHaAk30wW8MR8XDHq4arSUuaCLwwiPwyE9FMYMvg3YAomxz1w5Oab1li1G578GcltqWgPIOUSeR6Plj8Un/zGyjEj20t0DfnDmyzZVddMBHGgCUfGU8ZpY8mox1AyvBiXsM8isxaVKFboq8AlCBLjW3tQ42m4rJ4ydbOpAEFet11/0qbdqMmkT6ZQ1CnMqcClUpuCS8GvQl+Gy4QyKRdy0obPF4waub9Qe7xI3WTL212sW/7TWyjUx6kSMu1mx6LCiZWlJXUl+pqinIPj9W8jn+vp5CcJUBFa+AcsSt4D3gedCyV9kQC7UC+yby8NuJ2vvDZnTMa+Au0eu+b4uIKaYl19QV6nVdtgzDts1787XLXhl7dR7S6mYCfJLqSW/oE+BYUYY+hsGhn44md3Yg7kmnwrDMwzcClx+rtj06qszI2mfKreRHI3LHZURv4i0IY/RI519fN1uS0lmh7DpXV5FywdfT6INm/iGQ++nmMBTiI4rEBb6A6bf+BSWfHn/qFnoLPF5RCJgu8hXCLzY42CxNgoMy6PvfPuNr2lR2votjAuP9dm0oypFB8AGxCGEmqLqhiXDMRB+q+4BM9MQ7jcunn+6JGV5aYqe1aTLXdXkWblnd9htyaFeF2toX+B2na4tKi+1FBXmHtgnO513Wi+sVJ5kAwt/AMWgUsMJEuZlTgGCyDBSeGnRC4n336BSK9mz/Fnf/tOziXLs0d6J1X0GvM7ckcN2PKP6UY1TCpebdfOLLeAWl57gdrqOGGPRxQUYrgAQICGRwVfvJgL1PvEXVpRbgINDfRUPnzfck1e1fe+TUGAElYyFo2GeZwwWMoohbzVzz2w2z6mv1x90pa5xZIDOnn//dTXC9j6eYUxyaBiO8OWTbk15hQuYegUC/W/xmUaQwqe0AWYaO4F32xV9/4HWzWW7jxth1FTX6jbYMii6W9SwiFyEyEBtuWoBurImZCoVWlRqTPdFHci3RWcBYvoos0b52WOOnqZvdKa2WzN3WXN2fCrH1Coh1NJ2Mv6vmX5RZU2a1OZobEwZ3+5+lXdCOpvQz7OveaK//GKwCXGA9YLSQkrIE9UQI4h/snHRGLtJkc9bV+3/vorl40Y3lZodY21dVvyOmzqGmPWybG2rVY96AP1mKp7f0M1VfwQE88DQb5AIVs+rkrgEk4tBgOYCqJafk4eCD5+fHqhfaZWS8uRQgYScX5gFxSLxNkeIRMLUcTZQ7V7Px19XrUho22CbV+xFTTHaqfqavAGoHP8gWvAd/qbIxIkc2CdcYn9wh98tbhMgnkFl5z6xBs/+XRDvqkjT9OmVwOXG43ZiSkvU7w/xtMC4mJ8MUpOxyXKl+KSZy4UXH6+btGYjNqrSg+ZR7dYc3eac7bddxdFhL2MxKhxYJmpvNJs7iwxttpyKkvy3tCMoM4GPsQKobTyD1YGcRlnpccfP1KaoEAi6eH5VX44JZDiuRBekIh6ydUd+2jKZ+OLP88b1Vxo8owvPJE36oQpf58+D7SzxLq62L5u0iQ62Uz+hBRAVsIPPikJEQubTSSiQThmQJNdMHKX8OS35xltCyfdQP1+hJ/hIJ8oFiL4TkGkm/yFEXL2VN/6vf15+SeLyw/bmT4z2R2vvsKrKeThmWBAOArDzwNxOi4xwGl7eba4RFG20j+UwucwwZixdxm0l1Kic8GCFTkah624XpNTZ9euyb7U9eLjFOuXSdw3pFzHq2V89hnhUsl7AgO0auXSrDE1lxcdMoxuNeXw1MQTv6G4Q4r4OJLp988wlSAf7TZruq25tWW6t7Mu4oceo+G/YPyMi7JII8t8u+TQz79zUfw4xozTWoiZ300glgKQvCAdxidDE3YLp8HnJkKcqh/f63nh8RXG3G15mU1FlvbSwqYSG6i6yLZdm7/TbKn50U+p3wsDHCCPl4LAZRgSVuQtS1LUheRHCg/wTLvfPdNg+9xYQu9+Sp1+6kPwkIJaUMDP93AE3OQKkxd5WJD6e+i991oqKg7odLu1etDB0nFLr6jgO/GSzmTExSgRrYBVmAlEgRh+4WgHcSklzxqXX1D4HBmYTyWTsTDfEhGLJv0IS+LR7TuWaY31emOL3dhYYvw8e4Tj6Qco3JOCBvJFglLsjb4Ml0pR5BQVCsZzsyEXzZu7Jl99qEhXa1e3F+gOlBf2zp3KT+3DWKAyb/DzW//5gMHQqc3p0GfWFasX6sbQwV1wNIjwv7wjX1oAR177/j8tg7gU7MPTgrAdkBJeAUqerAaH8MTookyBUFCOB/j1Hr4O2ruh7t9+ttqsPWK3H8rNBdUajB2lZS2lpbOzxgSXruBHqcnr5zV1vs9Z8eP8jLaMLexDWOgNLl++2FRYU3zF+gztmhzLrBHGeTn2BRm6xWOyF2ePWJwxfPXo7HkXjliQk7dIm7vBkLEx7+sNFerGCiOoym6aq8mTPpuHsQe2xBQ3KxW6ApaVBAWukAWMP3bxZ4FLXPElI8rnJOMc0HLwq9hLpgQ1N32kzj9qNdfZ9Q2lxsMF+uof3UqBXlY/wZDAnmLI0Uq6ASBSYXWoPXDK0GS+cToMgYvem7bFYNxvzkO19Ubt/OwMOriVIo70VZHQkeef3aLRNGVltOlGNtjy1mpyaPUqigZDPI/715Q4IhOMOWI5GYZEisUQ8TM0/m6FcQnWQRAHWmbrEscg8WtY4ExZOHDyjqRYn2F5iTQ5xvdHRx3U0+yZ/PIn2ZlHxpaDqi0Fx/Pymg26ffaC5bf9gOdx+OZ9IBFKLTIYXM92Swp4engqyuta+cM71o67/EDFNZVX3biz4tptl924ddy1uwsnVI2beGCcfW+58ejE8n1lpbsnXrZxwthN3yw/fFP5HsvF9fZM0DFT3v7ykvW3/xM/zBrxIJKMhiM8Vz3YI2XI2RQBEOjJ2eMS9F8KGhBngpCcJaWYx82eBLj0e+aOLztSUV5pya8vNnZMHLvUYiBHp3JHG0uWdYaXML4Ul4KYU+Ug/pIR+I3g757fbTAfLzScKNTXFtunjRnJD9ECj4jAwbIU61kwc4VWXZeX2W4Y3VSQsy5zFH00nQKeMD9lxdpwtoVfQ4P2hbX9P/PjaBaCYN8hxmPbggUc1iUlBifGGcdgLMV8TzQiw78IdEGRQhT1MLwqd70y5lLQZqupsdjeZdRXm0zT1FqqPExyMCqeXxHSH2wJxKPopr37XxmT97omnzZu4BdO+GAbItTvpF4Pv7TD0UzhDvK38h3XTid5Ajx1tXnT0uHDO01GpkJrpdX0qS6Xjh4ib79Y46Egcl98CUmKD4Zaeg/6cva4VChd+IfAJdwcMkXYvqSUCom7G2MR8jnbnntylTX/UInhZImp2W6bO3IkZ4EBLy+kcf/RdV7C4IQGVQnAAJHY+Z9wqcgqxcE1qnUd/O5tB0zWxpKC2kLjnmLrwZ/8Cz+4kpKCsVSIp+fjVFs5y6iutetazGMazVl7crOb7/5XXndg83LWuIRpPN2VKxhVPv9uJY1LsMC+Q2zcc+U1DA5+xCyc9HqAoUjQE0ViLVwkQAX4+oXhdLr7eQEXurtiPmhFuX2HLq9Bl9M7tnS5xkifrYdMecjFjB0wzr4BUsIXKvf4uu59bIW9fOPdP2ZnJ2EQYKEToQhSddQejoVdEr+XxBGlUPoOMTDnCTXcfFubyQrqsVsP5I3ZYDLW3/dbXrLnl3hxF5jLobFQYKQM+f8Cl6DBLa5QjoBTxmUi4Ev7cdjOkIf2bXkz4+sHx5kbyyyHMzJ3mqy0bAl5PJyQCX2B+xe3m6At0QZ/CHTjd7r+dNNSXDCSgKL2ztZZjpgLmwqMdWUFn4y+hBbNE4+UpOfQ/NEgBfpW3XhF1ThTvTmj2ZTVaLfP15n4WTMYcu7U2RXFQAKI8OYAqOLT/85FxJcoYF6kO+jq3WoT7a3imwNj4vF4hDiEkeMnqqDr+IHQs1fiu/QYKhB60Ks8IX/orn9eZ9MeK8ivMWm26yz0wSzy8ivIgOyUxA8+4doAggMWZ5JONMwfbZw7KlfaspTiPWLVBooPreR5In6WHDDitUSEAVBfXi/pR5QajdHC2asuOQ/UaM6vM2iqC0s+0hmoqwU1eBOIaEVfhmCVRhsXfsvA2eBSIaUa0OCWOA1VycmAo3/K66/iMw7LxN7ES91162+asKkwt67YWJeVfWLsxH333cu4jDAuURvysLCCS/yAHLiJ/4xL5ZutP05IRKTt22bm6qvNRc1mw/Ei06oJpVRfwzNxwg1hyELJBMXdoemvrLFnVdsyuwo1zfbCmaOyvUuWszhZjH9lGXonoNeLMf+7lkFcCnGgk6BX7RPi783h5xIdMIfoWDAuO2PkifFMJK+Cg7wi4EzbP1g4RwfTyrnzjWPqxxWcLDKvGjkm+fq7wAHLHMk+7B/FXJJ46geWIBhxT/1ku2nCuoJyftlDykFSOMW3ZfGKHoQBZlBzPMjvPQnL4QD+hCaw2e06ubxYB2ooNnWatA0m66I8bXD+bL4pDuOQgtnlwjWgMNLEDxCsWsDX89hjO43GZqupzm5cpdfQnBnKM0N8ghjB9IUo4irlUvET0IHRU2IanrCPNjTd+71bheEUlAiSpzWxcNpcS9aRIsNAof2YyfiezUTdbbyOL+wlJAbiCtFJ0U8Of0HYNchnujkcRaoR9De+8fo6e9lxg7XNVrDToo9Me5vjmQCGggMfaDOrouwlV8vU/OFHSw0DY4tr8nS7raXr7/gXDpYkBeBs5oXuDTaUbo0VAyTYUHiSEjJMA9iFJiXZPMXldfMXVe87wJcL9oY09m9XFD8ODYalgUmDNtOHubaqm+/id3yh/6lkOCXB9YTYYQspiBswMAoIP6CvEcSbMHWRfqYDGz9UX1JXaGoqLJibk00rllPQw+EXKoXj54FBdBWhpJf6uhZfds0KQxm9NxPb/OQXRIB/Es+ZKfKCN+F8kJuSEuINaZAFCysS6H7vTdC2vEy/zdyi0e7S6VdfOYkGungOSwoA2W45jNEK4GpxWTLIxkoOe+HuHY89gVitQatrtphWZWWyT4w4GZcYF5yDTuH8eCIJww6eAxSLyiD2ZZzcQAC+RLwvEe6kqHvRz3/dMW0mh3F8tzkOQemC5Gxe/YOb9o+1tZryGoxZq2xZ3vf/xIwlYmEfzKUYeg5tIEohR/QIe4BWVCAGnD8QfyNlCbjhBz4utO8uLTthL6rKU++umEAecRsRLhFw425ypTx/55v61mqtsVprbdNaGyyFS9QZtHk5Sa4wa3SUY3qEQ35EIDDekLMkbkVOoIthXikFfMFBKCX7IvwELLAQ4bf5+WMDn++4q+QyfpUfv1WT54NF7juoYPz31Zc0LhHJxZh4dWRxbsGCkQY6doyi/pjbiXb9MvtH1nWE+2G+txq+HV4Z0TyOBmEpw31Mx3dPyTi/a3xJY1nR+wV6ajnBeIYDdog3tSJhQjCN0Y730+xZ72TmfWgppaN11NsrQjTWYzmRBCmcoWYgGZeIjmOnIMVodbWB5ueOOJJ5cbvFVFNgXZqnpsoD1N9OMYcvheiB19VZp/EFBLCZk5Jxfry68d9+sz1X32KwVOfm7bNa6eP3KeJAfAAW2D8rcoaSgI04r/N5owkQ+s4YgkmO9FESyHA0Lp3/7uXX074aHrwULD0CR7kTiWAqRNWV7466uG2cvVYzqnaidXG5gRqrye0EG7CtYZ57E+jkYIW/+KfiqsBtlMIc70TI0Ububt9LL64rLDpQNnZPUdESvZrWLIfcwaQiDGzgIpgMvr015CaXY+ctP9huLusovexIlvqE3bT+ihLy8JPW3BOfm5tHxOjBT4rzc61s/9G48oI8DmaAzpTy5qMghbw8aX+k/r6SyyNbDpArwuup4j2MgDmgiQ0WlkJfdVH8ONoTt/KLNj646JLVuYYVd95K/i4eCbgnZW2GPfKgrg8GSAgcKQ4n0sH06ZS1haZdmSN2F5g2/OaXFPEnU1Ax7ncqwCEp32iEqnyOVVfduKCoYseTT1EYMI1znC0ELcVlEId5g/2N8v3GKMl4OIRsIxWOSH4f3zbv7j5y349WW0ceMWsai0q3Ge0H7riTXN2U8vsp0oF8LeBnPjHS/ISWotwhcnc03Xv/1jxDq9FWp9Gvzc6iOZ9QjN+FqWBDnIarwslgwBvhd1rAloI83GngFGPj53j6RP202+6cfMP3yY18OSgl+QFRF0+g47wYtTXRrI8XZ42utphrjZY99uL+3/2eXC6onU88lONnvxkPBJ2toX40gSb5JZ0g4AYEPmUXRbpp7+bVxeW7zaUbdNbJozJaZ77FKg3TMSguvpB5hiOGwfbxiuXJ6ncLzFtLylsmXn5Sb/ksK3f/g49SexfHo/FYMsYrQBgRYDA9fiD0GfYX5kZEq2FAlFd+xes5u/ofvvy6TX94nTz8JLCY7mOFRzfxySM7yMZXXgQuYYRkxEzwU9zMguysExWXfzTWfPzlp8jZRZ4enkiPO3mOENoC5mQYMeioFIv7owPt7KREfLnh5hvX2cwHLCa+L3XfNugozolCBui5zKtHDpllF5s1c26GfqGxJLFzQ9LbKTRW9A02R4LvlkEikuESiUTEw00iBRbZBjMAbQm7A7NeXViaVVlkOmEtPmofP09noyOHoSTw9IAm9wSSEy4H1swHwcMGuNubH3xgn62k0WxrKSxal58Xn/IaxXpj5A5JITTA+QdGCdYlyWYJA4CMBgRPx7rld/CrYjv79v76oT8UjD0w+R3CRWG+xQS1c+QdFnf9Ipp0OVofffjDCy9ur7i2tmTSzByzPHchhVxQAJjcXl44DUJPoPQD/CiKsFyQbcTLFOwmXws1HlpwzeULstQ1V9/0XoZ6YOoUSjhiMiIrweMQsZgEz6jQ14VoSt646nWjdm2BrW/C1VXG0k+1Rbv+/RFyeMgNofmiiSD64pcSUPCwNw7i0QGJaQLgMoHYUnnLZGP7/ROunHnPw3wfpzfMj1XxoPOtW+isGDOBTYjpb4VLdIwzQsYCGlqlyT1ZUrLQnPOnzPPjr/6RettI6mWrITsoCT/FL71FzC3UHkJ2wEq1vfgcaEFZ+daKihmjRrheeJrCvTLkD3wgrPEFk243365BDhpo23TZxLayK2Z8/UJyNVGym+9v5eAgDU1ZZmjGE7zMwOuzYEm8L1ggEvkTBi/Ks0KgY5unZ5+3y6xtKBm7N69gra5o5w9/Rt09FA3G/E425JyjcPc4/8XIxV3k61593Td32gqPmExVFuOBSeM23nEz34mcVF4VFOXn+ZFDwCyFusnfS/wOMzdTrI+iveTtooULdnzrO0vVhVPUZjpRRQERHPOiP5AhhgvVQIhIET1u79T3/6Q6f59t0v6y62Zay0OfLUXNMg3EyR2XehNJRH78Gp0gO8hIGE3ATIJCXdRWu/qKir2XXXHgquvfHJPXOWUqPycE4MKCDEIhDQZ8MTohq7CMwD2JKLDfs3TOOxbTVkPxnlz7AdukpcaxCyuuod27yN1Hof4kMTTFu6iY2ZByZz8sqWJBvTJ1+j3z1jxYdPmyh5+lbjcNwCpBehEMBSR5yqso6oBL0qx8lUXBJQoa4SagDTNGX3zYYj549fg1E+wzcrPWf/sG2rWJehoo2M+mMdjHt1Dyq4Fbqfskdbc2P/u76dZi0KzC0rf1urbfP0VdJyjRF/K38z1vcAo+D+e8KVze4nvxiQ1jMvsNRVtHZNL86fyyyZBDPOYMm6FwgnAplcYlW0rBGrCI1McDp49oTKKBXqaVsz5TDzto0TWWldXbxm3NMS/MMsmvvEO9Ts5F+FY6D88fwMeGfGxDgbNNn83TaStt1uYi+8lCy8ES85qKwrY3nutf8int3EpVVVRzjOqP8lNdh7bRvh20dSNtX8/0+bL6yc8v+c51S0zWHYaSPbqSz8ZW8P2miXZ+niEEPCGFYNsTdw3mvP4guXy0ed+0PMsKU/nqoomTtbrWyS+Tp5NcrUibOP6BcEBIceCLfH3k7AYFP3p/qla7wmxdVz72LZMhuXo5h3oID/j/PxagEKI6hQ/GEy/WQ0ywbJyTIQfdsn7JhEkHxl9zsKDkcPHYnePGTR41/MgDv+Y3cAw08SsFw+K1mvy+FySm4j5O2MXGHnnTge0P/uFhbfnGR1/kdyjz62siMZ9bJCG8rqvoBTeMr781LlEz6ufwgmi+3bTRbNoyadyCYssSu31mrn7uaMvBq273P/oSzVhI23bSsSqqOkTbt0X//MbCgnHLDWNXl10Nmj62YsczT/ALm8mRTIn7zcM+BhDE2ttKlZsPPPpvi9XZvaXjezN0Dsu4veOvIFiCY7XkDqac3mgs/ayBQgpbUUQ52M3vfOK8iV9c29NPW7eBdhUa6/NHtpeZDmmyWooL64zWDlvFhks0gd88SDt2UnuNeLskENzAL97taKM5M+q/f8terabVZHBaDQ6z5vioYW12y9asMVuy1TtH6rdfrN14Ue7ai7NWjBi17NLR60fp1o7UrxrDtFJnXllUvKGktNJYclhtP2AoH3jkMX61FWF0Oajgid4YmOVbLTk+BmHMQgm+caXycOWv73nn4tGHCq/YqSldZ5pIb35CWw/R8SZq91JdD1W30paDseff3nP5LaD1eWVb7Jd9ZC44/OxD1HkcORb/nx88yzM4SCIdR9iA2BR2JN1WIpkKYkckDFACbYg1W5rannvqk8yvHx+v3WfOqC0z7DXmrMq8+HObrvWu2+OvPEcfv8U0+3365D35jdcbfnH32tKJMw3Fz6tLfHPXUQs8IVSa3Q7iMUTWIpBFY2J48A1cgrCRHq2vsgzZS64crUAF/2jQ0qZN1NHE77Hd8Hnsz29tGnfTIvX4aWOs7xmK37WX/tlk+bPW+K7B+rHGNktb/F62pfKX94No6y6GIAV9SZc74ORICLYN8bLL9auJ5feUWJ61at4aM3JxVtbyi0bMOe+SKSNzXjbYnyqZcGdRub+zz+eHJ2I2FErzBMJY40AQCVbyt3f85HuXTfpNYTFokUm/fMRFM7MunmXKfnvEsLm5+QsvUc8brv0k1/q6tezfy4t69m8hX+dLv/jR/UUlvy8ofkWrf23kiDm52QszRiy85MKZ56nW5WYuHHbB59maVRdlrVFlblLlbrxAs2a4ZlmGekWucdVI4/LhhkWXakGzxmin5ua/k5kz89Lc+aO174xW09ZNJPXDPrEzhIcN8FupwD5gw4OFLcXVyjChfn4fy6E9nnseWK22zRlpmppZ9Jx+4gvWK6ZbK6bri17NNkwzli2wXTl1uBE0L7+887dP0+7dHDZIAynywE4mUkmRdaTtJL6BQWRjPKeLAlzGkE+LeIxiSYTESIOQosFFnNw98OhPV5fnL1ZfslmXs1Ov2WHUrdflL7fo5pg1oHfVY97T535qNryfnbVtwmX00mR+ibUzQc4QPzyUSjgDTngruIN0YIsPhZO/GShRlLwHbYjoTTT2wc/vIqeD/IjG+jj39Dg4uKmtaV+yaOuLzy/91d2L7rhj5Q9/tP7Ouw4/9oRjxiyqqSHkyKBQKB0swf0KYphDoxF9AZ1hpHios5fccGTd5OrnJDEagcQReKJl5mKQ0p3FFzJX2Es4dLaXMt/+BWEFo0xOt+DTycqAvD4QIleMHBLnz4h+Y6zdvMbLdksMo08iX4TvcPLw+x2ZfOiak5xe6gtQT4h6Ivw/vGA8AgG+0Q77+91pcjrJ5+ST+50cb6GbvIKVQDIHD8PDgy+OLNEPXhdAp9EgCLt52iU1wC/fD7ZSZ420b1f9rAWrn3979j1PfHzHrXPvvGXB3T9e8+Qjhz56f2DfLhA5+zkdDsHb+Pl/peGbYBkT6Ao3JHAJwWAvcCk6KgSFbrKLh0IwD4Cy8Pohfiow7KDuFtq/xz13Xs3vX9p89z3Lbrvz4+u+M++2H4E23PNA9SuTvUuX0aFD/J8iwMD7Y/ygK2wKvzRUEit+CCvF3DsUjm1zesCUIUsP1ldaFFyKrALapjSJlNPvl3zKu++VXTzjyolpBKFbPw+PC0bewfdEArg8kYSQHCejBjHZAMFJLBvWXlyNPVwT8twwJcX/FSL7OVtPxYFIZBwgHFc6OUTp3rI0BC5RHXDJ0k4wNEGIpuLw/ahE8imPYyqDIhhAas0wRjgKDQE/YiFAPFnDkwnJFNcVFc9MMpgwBjHxjDJ8VRJ6AoJ2KcuiEaY4EjiYDMRhEbQLvwbMAZTKQ5vsTFn3MFqoAok2f4EfkRtiA7Ehsol+dvoIsuMergSYQioY6KZAI4UQbvYm+T5TtAcCm0jPkWqIx/L53gsIUbgSRZjAn7AhirrhE/uErITg+EQOBDFgvCiEglN5IJI8kw8DgTjSFeQ32CPL5kQ7zGoGmxJTXuaFrqPvuICxiPQI6S1wiQq5auAErbMC8AjhA5t/M1wqTWJI2Wpy34KegCMEbWXpoduRsF+O+qVUUOJfwBLyDz+/ThJqjbBdiiSTCLzZVkAsCqwwyjgVxHeqKz1JITOPR8V/osRjLLNv4t24DOIeVL7TCXv4HgI2mWIdRoEmckOGU5zXp+KcVkYpFBCvoQryAw2iF5weCZwpowhcykmAK8h5Mq9sifeT8oUgcd8u/+S3YCYjqRRziAaAeDhPNlVM4vY0VB/mT1wAySgmUrHO6SHiHWL5B9xjEAVkw4wPSM/J2QYyJIBSEQ1TL8VbgNcoucU7YfhxKP5Phjy8bomOYOjFdLeYO4SSgXHUiIYEUJX6MUxgAGqAbYYIS40/0HX+6ZHIJfP/qRVle8c2SFlKxRDAFCokY0yRl7MbivArUzjvRu8UAKBy1jhUhcvRrpAnty2aAInNr7gwLsE93ARIMJ70BaHfaXVXpM9MsXdKwFYEOHkLSLAXCF9YklAq4IWZUxjmuEpoEirBtdjDx8R/Egz7BHDACLAF4zesygw7yAsSFZm3Us/pxJLlIjwIAMeaA5SI+edomJGWCsKvI6WE2xMBUZQrZ/+jEOwkL16nRKgrXiAFucOO8PuBcTJ+3GE1BUti8gK/udqhQ2zeAR9YNSZssAVnaye8PNpAvWJ5C6dyrbxGmbY3ykEIQfnEfpDQG1yIy8EzuiZAyaLigJdhxgEsm1L+ZOjx5Upt6Y5xN7gSMZxcMwj7mHtcxA9UCoCjYtYpZRyA0hACD+ASAyTkMFgn/k6DJlrAURA2+G9QVDgLF3pF1yB9II/3Yy8IIlE2QIPnp7f/ciyUjXTNQyRGBLyLofnqy5AfP9UroNMrbkRgWYc8HHKJYRbOmb2pMB2weKx74mKBDxAMRoqNBodEGCGYkhSuRTzHr+3jHqPKQRfP10LGDCz2U6gGpIhAYWZo8LAhYKeIAOczG0IufykybOFUDCrqZGgyQoEdcIsLhf6AQz4AfVLqV1SRWUMziuPDAfzEp+ADFyk2g0/jNkVDIHEOvlE5WuELlf3iY4hzVKMcisWTAC/aFcThBftNmdMjZgYnoTnUmSbwD4cN7pAteSW2d9grzhHhJZjBJjOD3dzlQcJPhXPBJ76xT5yP6uAE4O/4TkJBPJoKy0xKAA+2opyapus5rSrRib8gcWCIvupC9P8AjKTIqgXffnwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=' style='margin-left: 0px;'/>     
                                        &nbsp;</td>

                                </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td> <div style='border-bottom:5px solid #808080;'></div></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                </tbody>
                </table>
                <table style='width:100%;padding:5px;word-spacing:0'>
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td align:'left'>
                        <table style='width:100%;height:10px;'valign:'top''>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                            <td align:'left'><div style='display:none;'></div> 
                                    <h2>ihigjkj</h2>
                                <div style='display: block;top: -105px;'></div>

                        <table style='width:100%; height: 178px;'>
                        <tbody><tr>

                            <td align:'left'> 
                                <table style='width:100%;' border='0'>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                    <td align:'left' valign:'top' style='width: 15%;'>

                                    </td>
                                    <!--<td align:'left' style='width: 5%;' valign:'top'>
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </td>-->
                                    <td align:'left' style='width: 80%;color:#303338;text-align:justify;word-wrap: break-word;' valign:'top'>
                                        <p>jkgnbkvnkvb</p>
                                        <!--<a href='http://www.ymlp.com/'>This is a link to some related web page...</a><a href='http://www.ymlp.com/'></a>-->
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><hr /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        </tbody></table>
                        <!--<table style='width:100%'>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                            <td align:'left'> 
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody></table>-->
                        <table width:'100%'>
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td align:'left'> 
                                <div> 
                                    <h2>kvnmvbmbvm</h2>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody></table>
                        <table width:'100%'>
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td align:'left'> 
                                <table style='width: 100%;' border='0'>
                                <tbody><tr>
                                    <td align:'left' style='width:80%;text-align:justify;word-wrap:break-word;color:#303338'; valign='top';>
                                        <p>jgknkbnvnbvm,nb,mbv</p><br>
                                    <!--    <a href='http://www.ymlp.com/'>This is a link to some related web page...</a><a href='http://www.ymlp.com/'></a>-->
                                    </td>
                                    <!--<td align:'left' style='width: 5%;' valign:'top'>
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </td>-->
                                    <td align:'left' style='width:15%;' valign:'top'>

                                    <a href='http://www.saloc.in'>                          </td>
                                </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><hr /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody></table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody></table>
                        <table style='padding:0px;width:100%';'>
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td align:'left'><h3>nngnbvmn,</h3>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody></table>
                        <table style='width:100%';>
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td align:'left'> 
                                <div style='text-align:justify;word-wrap:break-word;color:#303338';'> 
                                    <p>jgknkbnvnbvm,nb,mbv</p>
                                    <br />&nbsp;</div>
                                <div style='color:#003E61';'font-size:15px;font-family:'Times New Roman';> <hr/>
                                        <span style='color:#CA3B2A'><b>SALOC Technologies PVT Ltd,</b></style></span><br/>
                                       <b>#274/14,New Guddadahali Mysore Road,Bengaluru-560026,INDIA</b><br/>
                                       <b> Voice:+91 80 2675 5000,Fax:+90 80 2674 7000</b><br />
                                        <a href='mailto:shivananda@saloc.in'>shivananda@saloc.in</a>

                                </div>
                                <div> 
                                    &nbsp;
                                </div>
                                <div style='color:green;text-align:center;border-top:dotted thin #C0C0C0;font-size:18px'> 
                                    <br />
                                    <b><i>Business for mutual benefits</i></b><br />
                                 <!--style='border-top:dotted thin #C0C0C0;'-->To Unsubscribe Click here<a href='mailto:shivananda@saloc.in'>:shivananda@saloc.in</a>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody></table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody></table>
                <!--<table width:'100%' cellpadding='4' cellspacing='0'>
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td align:'left' >
                        <div style='font-size: 8px;'>
                            &nbsp;
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody></table>-->
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody></table>
        <!--<table style='width:600px' border='0' height:'30px'>
        <tbody><tr>
            <td align:'left'>
                <div style='font-size: 8px;'>
                    &nbsp;
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody></table>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>-->
                </table>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

it looks very big but here one thing u make sure am storing image in byte array ..until now am not facing any problem .the created html template above is looking good if u want to see please paste in notepad as html then open it browser then u come to know ..fine actually when i send this template as attachment in gmail,after send email i get only text content as dis located manner mean not as original style but content not styles all are showing without style ....and one more criteria is our clients wants to see the html template directly on mail body not as attachment..please let me know how do i solve these problems  i wish i'll get perfect solution about this because i trust stack overflow ...please help your help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: where is your server side code effort for sending mail.you just paste only html code!!!!!

Comment: @shankar.parsanamoni hey don't be rude, please add a comment to allow OP to improve the question

Comment: Try to give image as http link instead. And by using `StreamReader`   you will be able to send the email with html template.

Comment: THe content of the HTML template is not really relevent to your question, wheras the code you use for sending the email is. Please post the relavent code

Comment: @Schuere:your question is not relevant here. OP mentioned it very clearly

Comment: @InvernoMuto,I hope you understand Ben Robinson statement.

Comment: @Ullas, my bad, didn't saw that he tried that. deleted comment.

Comment: perhaps do look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26417507/asp-net-email-attachment-displaying-inline-on-mobile-iphone

Answer (score 1):

I suggested you to upload the image to web server and change the image path in the html file something like `http://domainname.com/imageName.jpg`.

**Code**

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/emailer.html"));
string readFile = reader.ReadToEnd();
string myString = "";
myString = readFile;
string mailServer, mailFrom;
int port;
string mailId, mailPass;
string subject;
string mailTo;
try
{
    subject = "Subject";
    mailTo = "receipient@gmail.com";
    mailServer = "smtp.gmail.com";
    mailFrom = "Mail From Text";
    mailId = "sender@gmail.com";
    mailPass = "xxxxxx";
    port = 587;
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(mailId, mailTo, subject, myString.ToString());
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(mailServer, port);
    System.Net.NetworkCredential nc = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(mailId, mailPass);
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    smtp.Credentials = nc;
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    smtp.Send(mail);
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alertmessage", "javascript:alert('Submitted successfully')", true);
}
catch(Exception ex){ }
```

Change subject, mailTo,mailFrom, mailId, Password as per yours.